# Is level set near a maximum value a circle?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $f$ be a $C^2$ function defined on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. Let $0 \leq f(x) < 1$ on $[0,1] \times [0,1] \setminus \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $f(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})=1$. It has no critical point except $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$. I wonder there exists a number $0<a<1$ such that $f^{-1}(a)$ to be a circle.

By the smooth manifold theory, $f^{-1}(a)$ is always a 1-dimensional submanifold. Since $f$ is continuous, it is closed. Thus, it is a compact. But it can still be a line segment.

Any reference are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's one way to do it:

Assume the contrary that $f^{-1}(a)$ is a line segment for all $ a\in [0,1)$. Then there is $c_a \in \partial ([0,1]\times [0,1])$ so that $f(c_a) = a$. As the boundary is compact, there is $a_n \to 1$ so that $c_{a_n} \to b$, where $b$ lies in the boundary. Then 
$$f(b) = \lim_{n\to \infty} f(c_{a_n}) = \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 1$$
and this cannot be true. As the level set can only be line segments or circles, you are done.

There's another way:

As $f$ has the maximum only at $(\frac 12, \frac 12)$, there is $\epsilon>0$ so that $f(x) <1-\epsilon$ for all $x$ closed to the boundary. That means $f^{-1}(a)$ for $1>a>1-\epsilon$ will be a closed one dimensional manifold **without** boundary: that is, a circle.

Comment: I am studying manifold theory but I am not studied boundary yet. Can you explain why $f^{-1}(a)$ does not have a boundary? Is there a formula $f^{-1}\{bd(a)\}=bd(f^{-1}(a))$?

Comment: If $f^{-1}(a)$ does not contain the boundary, then think of your condition that $f$ has no crictical point. Which means that locally $f^{-1}(a)$ can be written as graph of a function defined on an **open** interval. So it is impossible that $f^{-1}(a)$ will have an "endpoint". @Guillermo

Comment: I guess I understand what you mean! You may use the implicit function theorem to show that $f^{-1}(a)$ is a locally graph, right?

Comment: Yes. The only situation that $f^{-1}(a)$ is a line segment is that it contains the boundary (so the "endpoints" of the line segment lie in the boundary) @Guillermo